# Using glob and os to put files into folders & rename?

Tags: python, python-2.7, glob

I have a huge folder what contains about 5000 files with names similar to:

```
Rop OE[1932].exo
Make Dat[1932].edd
Back W'E[1934].exl
Pack Trees Pop[1944].exl
R.P END[1962].exl
Original CL0[1998].exp
```

I want it to **create folders** for all of these files with the name from the file above (without the extension) as seen below

```
Rop OE[1932]
Make Dat[1932]
Back W'E[1934]
Pack Trees Pop[1944]
R.P END[1962]
Original CL0[1998]
```

Then rename all of the **files** to remove the what appears to be a year so they appear as below

```
Rop OE.exo
Make Dat.edd
Back W'E.exl
Pack Trees Pop.exl
R.P END.exl
Original CL0.exp
```

And then all of the files to be put in their associating folder (same name)

What's the best way to do this, I've attempted to use glob to get the list and cycle through them all but it didn't seem to work correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), [os](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html), [shutil](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html) and [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) libs:

```
import glob
import shutil
import os
import re

root = 'path/to/folder/*'

for f in glob.glob(root):
    dirname = f.rsplit('.')[0]
    os.mkdir(dirname)
    filename = os.path.split(re.sub(r'\[\d+\]', '', f))[-1]
    shutil.move(f, os.path.join(dirname, filename))
```